# Pan UI to location of node in D3.js

Tags: d3.js, pan

I have a node , when that node is searched i want that node to be center of screen, how do i do ?

Search is implemented , but how do i make that node center of screen or make ui panned to that location of the node .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You would need to implement [d3.behavior.zoom](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior) and with that in place you can take advantage of programmatic zoom transitions like [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6238040).